# Using PHP to Insert a VARCHAR value to an already existing column within a certain row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason I cannot figure this out, PHP is not my greatest language.

I'm trying to insert a value into a column within a users row.

Here is the current array:

```
"UPDATE 'uf_users' SET 'Listings' = '$Listings' WHERE 'user_name' = '$loggedInUser->username'"
```

Comment: Tables are either 1). not string encapsulated, or 2). escaped with `backticks \``

Comment: In other words: UPDATE \`uf_users\` SET \`Listings\` - as ohgodwhy was pointing out, using single quotes around tables and columns is wrong. Use the backtick as a safe route in case you ever foolishly name a table or column as a mysql reserved word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't put quotes around column names or table names, or at least I don't. Also you may need braces around the variable

```
"UPDATE uf_users SET Listings = '$Listings' WHERE user_name = '{$loggedInUser->username}'"
```

If a variable is just a plain variable, ie $Listings, you don't need brackets, but when it's an array or object you use the brackets:

```
$string = "{$array[0]['key']}";
$string = "{$object->key}";
```

Comment: That got rid of my error, but now the data is not being inserted into the column when I check via PmA

Comment: Don't do the query just echo $Listings and $loggedInUser->username. To make sure those two variables are what they are supposed to be.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks guys! You are all Life Savers!